# vimrc how to invoke unix find?

Tags: vim, exuberant-ctags

i want to set the tags variable to the set of all `gotags` files i generated in specific folder(s) using `exuberant Ctags`. (`gotags` is nothing but the `tags` file renamed).

i put following lines in my `.vimrc` file.

```
set tags+=/usr/local/go/src/gotags
set tags+=`find /home/vimal/gowork/src -name gotags`
```

but it doesnt work and i get the following error

```
$ vi ~/.vimrc
Error detected while processing /home/vimal/.vimrc:
line  157:
E518: Unknown option: /home/vimal/gowork/src
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

how can i fix the error and set the `tags` variable with the value: list of all the `gotags` files under one directory tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inventing new syntax tends not to work that well in practice.  Use `system()` to run external commands from Vim, not backticks.  Also `set` in Vim is weird, it doesn't evaluate RHS the way you expect.  Most of the time it's a lot simpler to use `let &option = ...` instead of `set option=...`.

Anyway, to answer your question, you don't need to run `find(1)` for that, plain Vim functions are enough for what you want:

```
let &tags = join(extend([&tags, '/usr/local/go/src/gotags'],
    \ findfile('gotags', '/home/vimal/gowork/src', -1)), ',')
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but somehow only the tags from `/usr/local/go/src/gotags` only are being checked, other tag files listed as a result of `findfiles` are not being searched.

Comment: i checked help for `:findfile()` and found that we need to use wildcard `*` for downward search. so should use `findfile('gotags', '/home/vimal/gowork/src/*', -1)`